# How to Communicate between PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I wrote a JavaScript function to convert GeoJson data to WKT format. It works when i get the input value in the javascript code directly. But I don't know how to get the input from the php and send it back.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
  $geojson=file_get_contents("clipfeature.geojson");
  $WKT = $_POST['wkt'];
  echo ($WKT);
?>
```

So it gets geojson data from a file and I want to receive the converted WKT code from the Javascript function.

Please help me finish the JavaScript Code:

```
   function converttoWKT (){
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "readJson.php",
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function (data) {

    var JSONObject = How to give the value from PHP to this Variable;

    var coordinate = JSONObject.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
    var type= JSONObject.features[0].geometry.type;


    var coordinate1 = "";
    var coordinate2 = "";
    for (var i=0; i< coordinate[0].length; i++) {
     coordinate1= coordinate[0][i][0]+" "+coordinate[0][i][1];
     coordinate2=coordinate1+","+coordinate2;
    }

    var WKT= "\""+ type + "((" + coordinate2;
        WKT=WKT.substring(0,WKT.length-1);
        WKT=WKT+"))\"" 

    sendback ( );

}); 

    function sendback(){$.post("readJson.php",
    {'wkt':How to send the value of var WKT back to php 'wkt'
    });
    }
```

Comment: have try json_encode($_POST['wkt']); in your php script?

Comment: Also set your header in the php file. The javascript is expecting json so you should give it json. use:   header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

```
var jsVar= "<? echo $myVariable_value_goes_in_here; ?>";
```

or, as mentioned above:

```
var JSONObject =  <? echo json_encode($WKT); ?>;  
                  // this NEED TO BE json, otherwise syntax error in JS!
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know your return data will be JSON, you can just use `$.getJSON()` for convenience. This is a `$.get()` request paired with `JSON.parse()`. With `$.getJSON()`, the JSON is parsed on response. To send the data back, just use use jQuery's `$.post()`.

Here's an edited version of your code.

```
function converttoWKT() {
  $.getJSON('clipfeature.geojson', function(data) {
    var coordinate = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
    var type = data.features[0].geometry.type;

    var coordinate1 = '';
    var coordinate2 = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < coordinate[0].length; i++) {
      coordinate1 = coordinate[0][i][0] + ' ' + coordinate[0][i][1];
      coordinate2 = coordinate1 + ',' + coordinate2;
    }

    var WKT = '"' + type + '((' + coordinate2;
    WKT = WKT.substring(0, WKT.length - 1);
    WKT = WKT + '))"'

    sendback(WKT);
  });
};

function sendback(data) {
  $.post('readJson.php', {
    'wkt': data
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem. At first, the php still show error: Undefined index. Because I refresh the website but didn't refresh the javaScrip. At the end I just push "Shift"+ refresh, updating the javascript and it works finally.